# Why Lord Krishna is also called "Bankey Bihari"?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavata-purana

In Vrindavan,there is a temple of Lord Krishna named "Bankey Bihari" and Lord Krishna's another name is also Bankey Bihari. So,why Lord Krishna's another name is Bankey Bihari?

Comment: Lord Sri Krishna in his childhood lived near forests, one is Vrindavan. he roamed, played, and showed many miracles in those forests near the banks river Yamuna. so he is also called as "Van ke Vihari"

Comment: @Vishu (Responding to your note on meta) This is my understanding too The "bent" posture is called tribhangi AFAIK. Never heard before that banke means tribhangi.

Comment: @moonstar2001 : Yes. Thank you! I think Bānke means bent in some other Indian language then.

Answer (score 3):

'Bānke' means 'bent', and 'Bihāri' or 'Vihāri' means 'enjoy-er'. This is how Kṛihṣṇa, who is bent in three places, got the name "Bānke Bihāri" as gathered from materials.

According to Śrī Brahmasaḿhitā (verse 5.31), Brahma says the following about Kṛiṣhṇa:

"I worship Govinda, the primeval Lord, round whose neck is swinging a garland of flowers beautified with the moon-locket, whose two hands are adorned with the flute and jewelled ornaments, who always revels in pastimes of love, whose graceful threefold-bending form of Śyāmasundara is eternally manifest."

The Indian classical dance of Odissi is characterized by various Bhangas or stance, which involves stamping of the foot and striking various postures as seen in Indian sculptures, they are four in number, namely Bhanga, Abanga, Atibhanga and Tribhanga being the most common of all.[5] The Sanskrit term Tribhanga means Three Bhanga and according to K. M. Varma the term Tribhanga is not the name of a particular standing position but is used in the Silpasastra literature to describe the group of the “Three Bhangas”, namely Abhanga, Samabhanga, and Atibhanga.

This image below shows Lord Krishna's Tribhanga.

[image: Lord Krishna's Tribhanga image].

Comment: Ohh! I thought it was a posture of odissi dance style, threefold posture of krishna. because here( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayadeva) it is said that Jayadeva goswami popularised it. so do you have any other source where the threefold bending has been described in detail.I think it would be described somewhere in the scriptures otherwise how did people knew the bent place(which I think and correct me if wrong) are legs waist and head tilt.

Comment: The Indian classical dance of Odissi is characterized by various Bhangas or stance, which involves stamping of the foot and striking various postures as seen in Indian sculptures, they are four in number, namely Bhanga, Abanga, Atibhanga and Tribhanga being the most common of all. The Sanskrit term Tribhanga means Three Bhanga and according to K. M. Varma the term Tribhanga is not the name of a particular standing position but is used in the Silpasastra literature to describe the group of the “Three Bhangas”, namely Abhanga, Samabhanga, and Atibhanga.

Comment: I still did'nt understand. in Śrī Brahmasaḿhitā (5.31) Brahmadeva praises Lord Sri Krishna by saying that the lord has gracious threefold-bending form. now is brahmadeva refering this threefold bending form of god to tribhanga of shilpa shastra or dance?